# ERROR Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I get this error when i run `npm run ios` :

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

I was programming this code on windows when everything was working but after I migrated to mac everything shut down.
[image: Iphone emulator]

Answer (score 8):

Did you recently attempt to add/use use a new module?  I got this exact same error when I attempted to use @react-native-clipboard/clipboard when I should have instead been using expo-clipboard in my Expo app.  Toggling to the correct module fixed the problem.