# Expo "Error: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist", how to find the modules that are not compatible with Expo?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, expo-go

I am working on a React Native project that was roginally crated using the React Native CLI. The other team members had started working before I joined, so I'm essentially contributing to the project now.
I need to preview the app on a physical device, and since I'm using Windows and only have an iOS device, I installed Expo. I am able to run `npx expo start` and scan the QR code, which launches the Expo Go app, but shows 4 errors (and 1 warning).

One of the error says that my `"JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist"` but doesn't point exactly the module(s) in question, which makes it really hard to find out what the issue is.

I tried googling the error but there seems to be little info about it. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804638/error-invariant-violation-your-javascript-code-tried-to-access-a-native-module) but it doesn't really help in pinpointing the exact module(s) causing the issue.
I could also find reading the [Expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/) that I cannot add custom native code. Is it possible that the TypeScript code includes a module that isn't supported by Expo?

Another error seems to come from mismatch types ("undefined is not an object"), but yet again, I am unable to understand it.

I ended up creating a project from scratch using the Expo CLI this time, and copying only the source files, excluding the `android` and `ios` folders to make sure they're rebuilt from scratch, running `yarn install` to recreate the package.json, but the error still persists. So the error definitely is in the TypeScript code, but I do not have enough knowledge to find it out.

The errors, in the order in which they appears in the log console:

1)

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[7], "../features/auth/screens").OnboardingScreen')

This error is located at:
    in AppStackNavigator (at App.tsx:25)
    in AuthContextProvider (at App.tsx:24)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.tsx:23)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at GestureHandlerRootView.tsx:17)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at App.tsx:22)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
```

2. 

```
Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info
```

3. 

```
Error: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info.
```

4. 

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[7], "../features/auth/screens").OnboardingScreen')

This error is located at:
    in AppStackNavigator (at App.tsx:25)
    in AuthContextProvider (at App.tsx:24)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.tsx:23)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at GestureHandlerRootView.tsx:17)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at App.tsx:22)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file named = screens, and then see if it has the function = OnboardingScreen, see what lib and/or other functions it calls.