# Expo issue Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist

Tags: react-native, expo

I could not solve the issue in my Expo project. I am trying to run on my iOS device and this error appeared after I scan the barcode:

> Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.
>
> If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info., js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

this is my environment

```
  expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
    Binaries:
      Node: 20.5.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      npm: 10.2.5 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    npmPackages:
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-dom: ^18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-native: 0.72.6 => 0.72.6
      react-native-web: ^0.19.10 => 0.19.10
      transport-market:  49.0.21
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "transport-market",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have tried several solutions from the internet such as create expo development build, but the problem remains the same. It does not specify which module that caused issue.

Comment: Can you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75122441/error-invariant-violation-your-javascript-code-tried-to-access-a-native-module here they have the same issue as yours with @react-native-firebase/app package.